# Ingress nginx and gRPC comunication service error

Tags: nginx, ssl, grpc, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I've deployed Nginx Ingress Controller, manifest:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: namespace-servicename
  name: servicename
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-cf-dns"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - roabc.domain.net
      secretName: wildcard-roudh-domain-net
  ingressClassName: public
  rules:
  - host: roabc.domain.net
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: servicename
            port:
              number: 80
```

kubectl describe svc servicename -n namespace-servicename

```
Name:              servicename
Namespace:         namespace-servicename
Labels:            app=ro**
                   continent=eu
                   hub-id=eu-**-mad013
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=ro**,continent=eu,hub-id=eu-**-mad013
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.152.183.44
IPs:               10.152.183.44
Port:              grpc  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         10.1.252.108:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

But, unfortunately, grpcurl can't reach gRPC application, throws error **rpc error: code = Internal desc = failed to query for service descriptor"***.services.**.SearchList":**stream terminated by RST_STREAM with error code: PROTOCOL_ERROR****

```
grpcurl -d "@" -H "authorization: Bt** dert**" roabc.domain.net:443 
Error invoking method"***.services.**.SearchList": rpc error: code = Internal desc = failed to query for service descriptor"***.services.**.SearchList": **stream terminated by RST_STREAM with error code: PROTOCOL_ERROR**
```

gRPC app running in a Pod, constantly gives this error: **OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER**

```
 **ssl_transport_security.cc:1455] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.**
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to forward encrypted traffic to your POD and terminate TLS at the gRPC server itself, add the ingress annotation

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPCS"
```